Use of Apache Camel Spring Util
I am looking at a few Apache Camel Routes that use Spring XML and reference <util:
Example:
 <util:properties id="properties" location="classpath:staging-test.properties"/> 
 
 <property name="fields">
            <util:map>
                <entry key="Exported" value="Y"/>
            </util:map>   
 </property>

 <util:properties id="props">
    <prop key="adder">
        4
    </prop>

  <util:list ...

  <util:map  ...

I am looking for reference documentation on the proper use of <util: and descriptions of the various <util: options. I have trolled around numerous locations without much luck. Can someone point me in the proper direction?
